Celery Worker Fails with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Redis' in Django Project
I'm working on a Django project where I need to send periodic emails using Celery. My environment is set up on Ubuntu, and I have Redis installed both on my system and within my virtual environment.
Command:
celery -A main worker -l info

However, when I try to run the Celery worker, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 236, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 135, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 348, in worker
    worker = app.Worker(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 119, in setup_instance
    self._conninfo = self.app.connection_for_read()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 821, in connection_for_read
    return self._connection(url or self.conf.broker_read_url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 880, in _connection
    return self.amqp.Connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 201, in __init__
    if not get_transport_cls(transport).can_parse_url:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 90, in get_transport_cls
    _transport_cache[transport] = resolve_transport(transport)
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/__init__.py", line 75, in resolve_transport
    return symbol_by_name(transport)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 59, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/osama/Projects/send_email_with_celery/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 267, in <module>
    class PrefixedStrictRedis(GlobalKeyPrefixMixin, redis.Redis):
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Redis'

Reinstalled redis:
pip uninstall redis
pip install redis

Checked Redis Installation:
Redis is installed on both my system and virtual environment.
Ensured Compatibility:
Verified that the versions of redis, kombu, and celery are compatible.
Celery Configuration:
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'

What could be causing this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Redis' and how can I resolve it to run my Celery worker successfully?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

with you virtualenv active, run python and then import redis, does it fail? if it doesn't fail, what happens when you put redis on the console? (it should give you the path of the redis package)

@pleasedontbelong,it failed, the error stated no module named 'async_timeout'.
So i installed 'async_timeout' in my venv and it solved my issue. Thanks.

I get this same issue but only when I run celery through supervisor. When I run from background, no issues.
